# extra ' in bash script which cause the mvn to fail

Tags: bash, shell, maven, sh

I am writing a bash script to launch a java class in an in-house Java application server. However there are some (') which appears during class name substitution in the command below. This makes the launch fail as mvn expects the commands in a certain format.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

function launchClassInEngine {
CLASS_NAME=`echo \"launch-in-engine $1\"`

# echo as I would want it to "launch-in-engine MyClass"
echo ${CLASS_NAME}

# The problem starts here
# output:  mvn '-Dclass="launch-in-engine' MyClass 'id=20"'
mvn -Dclass=\"launch-in-engine $1 $2\" 

# so the problem is that while substituting the string at -Dclass= bash adds '
# I do not know how to fix this. Any idea or pointers
}


# Expect the below call to run
# mvn -Dclass="launch-in-engine MyClass id=20"
launchClassInEngine MyClass id=20
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
mvn -Dclass=\"launch-in-engine $1 $2\"
```

With this :

```
mvn "-Dclass=\"launch-in-engine $1 $2\""
```

The reason I think this may solve your problem is that you are (I think) hoping to pass the whole `-Dclass` as a single argument, but there are unescaped and unquoted spaces inside that string, so the shell actually sees three arguments :

- `-Dclass=\"launch-in-engine`
- `$1`
- `$2\"`

Try adding unescaped double quotes around the whole thing so that it is seen as a single argument.

Comment: Thanks Fred. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 issues

1. Using -x printed debug information which lead me to believe that that extra ' were being inserted
2. I was used to running the *mvn command as mvn -Dclass="launch-in-engine MyClass id=20"*. The quotes were to pass the entire string which consist of variuos instructions to the mvn plugin. So I assumed that inside the function the same needs to be replicated.

However the below scripts works just fine.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

function launchClassInEngine {
mvn "-Dclass=launch-in-engine $1 $2"
}


launchClassInEngine MyClass id=20
```